# MVC 4 project template featured section background color: can't change in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am just trying to modify the background color of the "featured" (light blue) section on the MVC 4 internet application project home page.  This works fine in Firefox.  I see no change in Chrome, it's just always the original light blue.  Why?

```
.featured .content-wrapper {
    background-color: #ffffff;
```

Comment: are you trying to change .featured or .content-wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default Site.css of an MVC4 application you are going to have the lines

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
```

within

```
.featured .content-wrapper { }
```

Chrome will be using them with a higher priority than the `background-color: #ffffff;` rule and that is why the featured text is still with a blue background.

Comment: Thanks.  So it will be the case that any webkit browser uses these lines at a higher priority, yes?  I assume the other two lines here `-ms-linear-gradient` and `-o-linear-gradient` will work with IE and Opera respectively, correct?

Comment: I think the priority of these is a browser specific rather than a standards thing, but I believe this to be true.